# Android list view item click in adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment class and corresponding adapter class. My Fragment class looks like this -

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), favourites);
        msgListView.setAdapter(myAdapter );
        return view;
    }
```

In MyAdapter,

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder1 viewHolder;
        MyClass favouriteMessage =  favouriteMessageList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites_fragment_list, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder1();
            viewHolder.favouriteMessagesList = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.favourites_list);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Update Your Views Here
        viewHolder.favouriteMessagesList.setText(favouriteMessage.getText());

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setFavouritesData(ArrayList<FavouriteMessageWrapper> data) {
        favouriteMessageList = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I want to implement list view item on click listener. Where do I implement it? If i try to do it in onCreateView of my fragment, it is null.

Comment: Can you send your error log?

Comment: if you make web request and that data if  you are going to display than in onpostexecute you have to setadapter on listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

set itemClickListener in fragment and do like this,

```
msgListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    MyClass favouriteMessage = favourites.get(position);
                                   String favorite_message = favouriteMessage.STRING_NAME;
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: The onItemClick should be there in onCreateView of my Fragment?

Comment: favouriteMessageList is an arraylist in adapter class.How do I access it in fragment?

Comment: sorry, it will be favourites - which arraylist is inside of your Fragment class. Check my answer again please.

Answer (score 0):

don't set adpter on create. setadapter after getting data.like http method set adapter in onpost method.

Comment: msgListView =(Listview)view.findviewByid(R.id.msgListView); msgListView.setAdapter(myAdapter );

Answer (score 0):

Make your fragment implement `OnItemSelectedListener` and after

`msgListView.setAdapter(myAdapter );` in your `onCreateView()`

`msgListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`.

Comment: I implemented this already but it gives me null upon onItemClick

Comment: can you post your onItemClick and don't forget to initialise your listView using findViewBytId(R.id....)

Answer (score 0):

Do all initialization in `onCreateView()` :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragementName, container, false);//put fragment name of your 
    msgListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    return view;
}
```

Implement `OnItemClickListener` in your fragment and
in `onActivityCreated()` setup adapter and `itemClickListener` :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), favourites);
    msgListView.setAdapter(myAdapter );
    msgListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I did not get you... Could you please explain it to me more detail please

Comment: Please post your entire fragment class, ill do the edit and you will understand

Comment: I implemented as your way... But still my list view ites are null after onItemClick

Comment: what do you mean by null items?

Comment: I mean upon list view item click, I get the value as null for my string... String favorite_message =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: use `adapter.getItem(position);` and in your adapter override `getitem(int position)` method and return `favoriteMessageList.get(position)`.

Comment: Please post your entire fragment and adapter class, ill explain

Comment: If you are not getting anything, why dont you post entire adapter class? @MariaAnasthesia

Answer (score 0):

you can implement onClickListener inside the adapter instead

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     viewHolder.favouriteMessagesList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //perform action
            }
         });

    return convertView;
}
```

hope it solved your problem